# Prove that $\operatorname {ht}(p/a)\leq \operatorname {ht}(p)\leq \operatorname {ht}(p/a)+n$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension

In the Milne's book [A Primer of Commutative Algebra](http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/CA.pdf), pg. 100, there's a proof that $\operatorname {ht}(p/a)\leq \operatorname {ht}(p)\leq \operatorname {ht}(p/a)+n$. I understand the first inequality, but I'm lost in the second inequality, when it says *Then p is a minimal prime of $(a_{1},..,a_{d},b_{1},...,b_{n})$, and hence has height d+n*. I don't know how it concludes that. It says that $p/a$ is a minimal prime ideal of  $(a'_{1},..,a'_{d})$ and $a$ is generated by $b_{1},...,b_{n}$. How this implies the first?  I'd like somebody help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The book says "*and hence has height* $\le d+n$", and this follows form the [Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem); see Theorem 21.6 in Milne's book.

If you want to prove that $\mathfrak p$ is minimal over $(a_{1},..,a_{d},b_{1},...,b_{n})$, then suppose the contrary, and pick a prime ideal $\mathfrak p'$ such that $(a_{1},..,a_{d},b_{1},...,b_{n})\subseteq \mathfrak p'\subsetneq \mathfrak p.$ Then $$(a'_{1},..,a'_{d})=(a_{1},..,a_{d},b_{1},...,b_{n})/(b_{1},...,b_{n})\subseteq \mathfrak p'/(b_{1},...,b_{n})\subsetneq \mathfrak p/(b_{1},...,b_{n}),$$  a contradiction.

Comment: I know that, what i don't understand is why $p$ is a minimal prime of $(a_{1},..,a_{d},b_{1},...,b_{n})$, knowing that $p/a$  is a minimal prime ideal of $(a'_{1},..,a'_{d})$

Comment: @CarlosVázquezMonzón Maybe you want to clarify this into the question.